# jquery ui modal dialog: giving an id to modal buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Im using the JQ UI modal dialog and have included several buttons in the dialog.

How do I give individual IDs to these buttons (in case I want to target them for some CSS updates)?.

TIA

Comment: give us some code to work with. e.g. the code that creates/opend your dialog

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
        buttons: [{
          id:"customID",
          text: "Your Button"
        }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set every single button configuration, for example:

```
<div id="dialogConfirm">Some message here</div>
```

and

```
$( "#dialogConfirm" ).dialog({
  resizable: false,
  height:180,
  modal: true,
    buttons: [{
      id: "someId",
      text:"some label",
      click: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },{
      id: "secondId",
      text: "cancel",
      click: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }]
});
```

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/QtYWm/2/